Problem in Android that only happens on OnePlus Smartphones
I have this problem
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/local/tmp/external/d14b78a5-ac82-4371-8791-e7433f6e2f706102300023160852134.jpg
       at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
       at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:450)
       at com.sienarsystemsmx.pocketcoach.principal.SocialFragment.startCamera(socialFragment.kt:2385)
       at com.sienarsystemsmx.pocketcoach.principal.SocialFragment.onClick(socialFragment.kt:2237)
       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1250)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1187)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3179)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:423)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

The code on startCamera is:
    private fun  startCamera (){
        if (!iniTempFile()) return
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        try {
            mImageCaptureUri = null
            val state = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == state) {
                mImageCaptureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    requireContext(),
                    "com.xxxx.yyyy.provider",  
                    mFileTemp
                )
            }
            if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImageCaptureUri)
                cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data",true)
                resultLauncherCamera.launch(cameraIntent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Error al intentar guardar imagen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.d(NewFoodFragment.TAG,"Error Creating File:${ex.localizedMessage}")
        }

    }

The problem is that I can't reproduce the error, and in the Crashlytics logs it only happens on OnePlus 8Pro Phone. The worst problem is that the reviewing team on PlayStore uses it and marks it as a crash.
Do any have some error like this.
I tested in a lot of phones. Even in a Online testing environment with that phone emulator and I didn't reproduce the error

Where and how you are setting the value for mFileTemp?

Seems it is a permission issue on oneplus device, you might need to confirm if users haas the right permission to access that file.  mostlikely file permission

this is considered dangerous permission so be sure user has granted before trying to access that file...

could help with right permission if you have not implemented
